# How to disable bean validation dynamically?

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation

When editing user data I want password validation to be dynamically enabled only if password is not empty. What I have tried is using an ajax request that renders the password component in order to disabled attribute from validateBean tag gets dynamic.

My bean has a boolean property disabledValidation which is updated when listener associated to ajax request is executed.

The first problem I have found is that being password an InputHidden when user writes its password component is rerendered (due to ajax tag) and what he wrote gets lost.

Besides listener associated to ajax tag is never executed.

```
<h:inputSecret id="password" binding="#{password}" value="#{userBean.user.password}">
  <f:validateBean disabled="#{userBean.disabledValidation}">
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="@this" listener="#{userBean.enableValidationIfPasswordIsFilled}"/>
  </f:validateBean>
</h:inputSecret>
<h:message for="password" />
```

Comment: you also can take a look at omnifaces validators utils https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/showcase/validators/validateAllOrNone.xhtml and validators section here https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. However it seems to use JSF Validation instead of Bean Validation